Sent file data of an image from client-side to server-side
I am tring to upload an image to storage (appwrite). As you can see below is that I have the file from client-side but I don't get it to the server-side. I've read the documentation from Appwrite and the file-data needed to upload is available at client-side but to upload it to storage I need that file-data server-side, I get an empty object. Can you help me with a solution for this problem?
Many thanks in advance!
AuthForm.tsx component:
const handleFileChange = async (e: any) => {
    if(e.target.files) { 
      await createFileId(parseStringify(e.target.files[0]))
      //It's here
      console.log(e.target.files[0])
    }
}

user.actions.tsx:
export const createFileId = async (img: any) => {
  const {storage} = await createAdminClient();
  //Not here
  console.log(img)
  
  const promise = storage.createFile(
    BUCKET_ID!,
    ID.unique(),
    img
  );

  promise.then(function (response) {
      console.log(response); // Success
  }, function (error) {
      console.log(error); // Failure
  });
}


When uploading files in a browser environment, you need to wrap the file in FormData. This ensures that the file is properly sent as part of the request to the server.
AuthForm.tsx
const handleFileChange = async (e: any) => {
  if (e.target.files) {
    const file = e.target.files[0];

    // Prepare FormData to upload the file
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);

    await createFileId(formData);

    // The file is here
    console.log(file);
  }
}

user.actions.tsx
export const createFileId = async (formData: FormData) => {
  const { storage } = await createAdminClient();

  // Ensure the file data is available in formData
  console.log(formData.get("file"));

  const promise = storage.createFile(
    BUCKET_ID!,
    ID.unique(),
    formData.get("file") as File
  );

  promise.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response); // Success
  }, function (error) {
    console.log(error); // Failure
  });
}

